# Does all linux users are present on /etc/passwd?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, system-administration

There is one user "user1" which I cant find in /etc/passwd but I can execute cmds like

```
$touch abc
$chown user1 abc
$su user1
```

These command runs fine, but if I try to chown to some really nonexistent user these *chown* and *su* commands fail

I was wondering where is this *user1* coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While logged in with user1 (after su user1) execute:

```
getent passwd $USER
```

This fetches user passwd entries across different databases. All users are not necessarily system users - they can come from LDAP etc.
Check docs on [getenv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getent).

Also check your `nsswitch.conf` to see all sources used to obtain name-service information.

Comment: Just to add: nsswitch.conf is usually located in /etc/nsswitch.conf